# Split Hashtable within a Hashtable into two separate Hashtables

Tags: java, split, key, hashtable

I am new to Java. I have been using Hashtables to read in different data with various keys and values.

I have a Hashtable within a Hashtable that I would like to split into two Hashtables.

```
Hashtable<String, Hashtable<String, Double>> sData;
```

Would like to split into something like:

```
Hashtable<String, Double> innerData;
Hashtable<String, String> outerData;
```

I'm not even sure this is possible, given I'm taking the outer Hashtable and changing the value to String, instead of another Hashtable. I thought I would ask anyway

Comment: I'm having a hard time comprehending what data is supposed to go where. Can you give an example of what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to use the inner Hashtable's key as a key in a separate Hashtable, but also keeping the outer Hashtable for use later. Example:

Comment: yes, thank you that is what I was thinking of, just wasn't sure if it was possible

Comment: i'm not entirely sure what outerData is supposed to contain, but if it is a mapping from the outer key to the inner key, this will only work if the inner maps only ever contain a single entry.  also, if there is any overlap of inner keys across outer keys, then your innerData map will be losing data.

Comment: for instance, if we think of cars, the outerData contains something general like the "Make" of a Car, while the innerData contains the "Model" and the "Price." Ideally, I would like to be able to pull the "Model" and "Price" (key2, value), but also keeping the general "Make" and "Model" (key, key2)

Comment: you can't map "Make" to "Model" if you have more than one "Model" per "Make".

Answer (score 1):

```
Hashtable<String, Double> innerData;
Hashtable<String, List<String>> outerData; // or use some multimap library

for(String key:sData.keys()){ 
   List<String> outerlist = new List<String>();
   for(String key2:outerData.get(key).keys()){
       outerlist.add(key2);
       innerData.put(key2,outerData.get(key).get(key2))
   }
   outerData.put(key,outerlist)
}
```

or if you want to avoid cross-hash data loss, you need new classes

```
Hashtable<Pair<String,String>, Double> innerData;
Hashtable<String, List<Pair<String,String>>> outerData;
```

Where Pair is a class representing your nested keys.  You could also just concatenate the strings, but this is messier if you want to work backwards.

Comment: What?  This doesn't even compile; you can't just iterate over a `Hashtable`.

Comment: outerData is continuously overwriting the same mapping, so you'll only get the last key2 value that you put in for a given key.  you're losing data.  also, if there is any overlap in key2 across the nested maps, you'll be losing data.